# Перерисовка окна с "аппокалиптическими" последствиями

Tags: winapi, gdi, c++

Создавал свою рисованную кнопочку (эксперимент - я знаю про класс BUTTON :))) и вроде все как бы нормально, по началу. Потом кнопочка перестает появлятся, потом перестает перерисовываться окно, а потом и вся винда. В чем проблема, что не допонял?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static HDC hdc,membit;
    static HBITMAP hBitmap,hBitmap2,hBitmap1;
    HDC bm; 
    HRGN hrgn=CreateRectRgn(100,100,250,150);
    static pString str;
    int x,y;  
    hBitmap2=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("off.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    hBitmap1=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("on.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:     
        hBitmap=hBitmap2;
        GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bm),&bm);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        membit=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(membit,hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:    
        hBitmap=hBitmap1;
        GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bm),&bm);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        membit=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(membit,hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        hBitmap=hBitmap2;
        GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bm),&bm);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        membit=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(membit,hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        x=LOWORD(lParam);
        y=HIWORD(lParam);
    if(PtInRegion(hrgn,x,y))
    {
        hBitmap=hBitmap1;
        GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bm),&bm);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        membit=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(membit,hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        hBitmap=hBitmap2;       
        GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bm),&bm);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        membit=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(membit,hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
    }
        break;
    case WM_CHAR:
        str +=(TCHAR)wParam;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
       hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
       BitBlt(hdc,100,100,400,200,membit,0,0,SRCCOPY);   
       TextOut(hdc,0,0,str.data(),str.size());
       DeleteObject(hBitmap);
       DeleteObject(membit);
       EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
       break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
       break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в винде (видимо ноги растут из личных качеств Б. Гейтса)

    потом перестает перерисовываться окно, а потом и вся винда.

Так M$ видят ОС.

Comment: avp, да ладно! Это симптом утечки GDI/User ресурсов (кот я не читал)

Comment: Конечно, утечка ресурсов (это в ответах @ganouver и @dzhioev). 

Комментарий о реакции ОС на нее.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать что лучше не использовать GDI & C++. Там даже кнопку с рисунком проблемно создать. Люди, переходите на Qt

Comment: Обычно кнопка с рисунком создается просто и быстро через класс BUTTON, а этот случай как я описал в вопросе эксперементальный и можно сказать не стандартный для кнопок.

Comment: @avp, честно говоря код не читал, а ответы увидел после того как прокомментировал. Хотя уверен, что у Реймонда Чена в блоге есть пост с правдоподобными объяснениями, почему такие катастрофические последствия от утечки в одном процессе для всей window station :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вижу как минимум одну проблему - вы при каждом вызове WndProc загружаете картинки. Попробуйте загрузить их только 1 раз:

```
    static HBITMAP hBitmap1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("on.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
      static HBITMAP hBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("off.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

Answer (score 2):

Больше всего похоже, что забыли выгрузить загруженные битмапы. Они загружаются при каждом вызове и не освобождаются.

Comment: Я не то что бы забыл. Я скажу что незнаю как это делать. Нигде не написано, что нужно выгружать битмапы. Есть такая штука как DeleteObject, но и она не помогает.

Comment: Вообще-то DeleteObject [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539%28v=VS.85%29.aspx] как раз про то. Нужно при выходе из функции его вызывать для всех ненужных более ресурсов. Или использовать классы [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35%28v=VS.80%29.aspx], которые будут делать это за вас автоматически, в деструкторе.